# How many fingerprints can we store using Android 6.0 fingerprint api

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

I am building an application which needs to store fingerprints of multiple people. Can this be achieved using the fingerprint api.

Comment: Did you tried to add any of it by API? Maybe you can scan until exception yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As per Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow, the system is capable of storing up to 5 prints at a time.

That said, the [Fingerprint API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/package-summary.html) that was introduced along with M is there **solely for authentication purposes**. That is, you won't be able to manage prints (add, remove, or even see them) from within an app.